# android read xlsx file with apache poi stop with error , how to solve

Tags: android, apache-poi, build.gradle, xlsx, xmlbeans

i'm using **apache.poi** 3.15 to read **xlsx** file from android . my app show error in 2 conditions 
**Condition one :**
if i run my app **without xml-beans.jar** , the app will be build and run and i can declear

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
```

so no error will be apear but if i change my code to this

```
InputStream fIn = cntx.getResources().getAssets().open("a.xlsx", cntx.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fIn);
```

app will successfuly build , after run will stop and show this error :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
```

**Condition two** : if i depend xmlbeans.jar , android studio will terminate build process and show this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class
```

this is my gradle :

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ramin.test"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    //enable Multi Dex
   multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false;
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/poi-3.15.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.15.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')}
```

**what i should do**

Comment: Did you look at any of the other Android + POI questions here? What happens if you follow the advice given in most of those?

Comment: yes i saw most questions in stackoverflow , any version has different error

Comment: i tried aspose.cell library and that is worked well , unfortunately is not free to use just has 30 days trial :( so again i should solve apache.poi issue. for next step i change apache version from 3.15 to 3.8 now i just have one problem with stax-api1.01.jar for this error ( "javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**finally** i found solution here https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX
. just need to append this jar files not more ! :

```
compile files('libs/aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5.jar')
compile files('libs/aa-poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-more-0.1.5.jar')
```

and other lines in gradle that we need to build :

```
    defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false;
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this help some one ...